# Drive relay with IRFZ44N

Tags: mosfet-driver

The output from an existing circuit gives me 2.5V and .15mA

I have setup the following circuit and it seems I cannot drive the relay. May I know why it is so?

[image]

Comment: Gate threshold voltage for IRFZ44N is Min 2V Max 4V, so with 2.5V you aren't guaranteed to turn the FET on (especially with that high gate resistor). By .15mA I think you meant 15mA (0.015A), and not 0.00015A?

Comment: No, actually it is in Micro Amp range :( Can you suggest any BJT or MOSFET which I can use to drive the relay with that driving source?

Comment: Why don't you use a buffer to drive the IRFZ44? A smaller FET with a pull up resistor should be enough.

Comment: 2.5V, or 2.8V? Your relay circuit has an input loading of 11k. 2.5V/11k = 0.227mA, but your 'existing circuit' can only supply 0.15mA? What exactly is this 'existing circuit'?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by 11K of loading. The relay load is 90 Ohms. It varies between 2.5V and 2.8V depending on temperature and etc. The driving source is coming directly from an MCU's IO pin of a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The relay is 90 ohms at 12V so it means it requires a current of 12/90=133mA. According to the datasheet of IRF530 the minimum threshold voltage is 2V. You need to provide more than 2V, say 5V to provide the amount of the current that's needed, 130mA here. The transistor in in triode region so the current increases linearly with increasing \$V_{GS}\$.

At a \$V_{GS}\$ of 10V the \$R_{DS(on)}\$ is reported 0.16 ohms. Therefore the power consumption by the MOS itself would be only 2mW, which is negligible. Again you don't need a power MOSFET, a smaller MOSFET with lower threshold voltage such as 2N7000 will be fine. Also in this particular application, there is probably no need to use FETs. Any BJT can be used instead as long as you can provide sufficient current into the base. Or as commented use a Darlington pair with the base resistor above 120k ohms.

[image]

If you use a MOSFET for low switching frequency then the current into the gate would be negligible, and it would save power if you're on a battery-powered circuit.

Comment: The problem is that the driving source is having very low current and I'll not be able to drive a BJT with that low current unless I use an op-amp :(

Comment: @RakeshMehta - not if you use a Darlington pair .

Comment: Yes @JImDearden, that seems to be the only option.. Let me try to do that.

Comment: Hi @driac16, one question though. How did you calculate the base resistor to be 120K. Can you please explain me for my knowledge?

Comment: Just use KVL. The current through the 120k resistor is simply 2.8-2Vbe divided by 120k, which is roughly 12uA. This is enough to turn on Q2 in saturation. You can use a bit lower resistor though as long as the current is less than 150uA.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pick a better MOSFET. Eg. [AO3420](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3420.pdf), but there are scores of them.

[image]
[image]

You will likely have to use a surface-mount part, but it's current year so that should not be an issue.