# What's wrong with my electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetic

I've watched every video on youtube to create an electro magnet for my school project. I think I'm doing everything normal but it's still not working.

[image: e]

Comment: Is that brass wire? Also, steel isn’t ideal but you should still be able to see the effect and lift small things. What are you powering it with?

Comment: What's the bolt stamped on top? How much current do you push through the wire?

Comment: Looks like you may have uninsulated wire which will result in shorted turns. You need insulated wire, and with few turns such as you show will end up with very high current. What voltage supply do you have?

Comment: I doubt that would work. Your wire has an enormous cross-section, a 12V 1A power supply would simply go into overcurrent failure. You need either a 1V 12A power supply, or 12 times more windings.

Comment: That's a really low resistance coil, you are probably just putting your PSU in over current protection mode. Maybe try thinner wire with more windings. 12V should need 12 Ohm for 1A. If you have a multimeter you can check the coils you make.

Comment: Did you measure the voltage and current under load?

Comment: If that bolt is high grade stainless steel (400 series) you will get no magnetic field from it.

Answer (score 12):

1. Steel bolts don't make good magnets.  Soft iron is much better.
2. With that low number of turns on the coil, you will have to put a LOT of current through it to get any strength out of it.
3. You have to have insulated wire.  Your coil might be made with varnished copper wire, but it is hard to tell from the picture.
4. To make that electromagnet strong, you will need a powerful battery.  That does not have to mean high voltage.  It means it has to be able to supply a lot of current.  A 9Volt transistor radio battery would be a poor choice - it has a somewhat high voltage but can't supply much current for very long.  A D cell has only about 1.5V, but it can provide a lot of current.

That coil will probably draw more than 1 ampere of current - I don't think your power supply is up to the job.

1. Use a soft iron bar (like a big nail.)
2. Use a thinner wire.
3. Put more turns of wire in your coil (like, one hundred or more turns.)

---

I'm going to go into "grouchy old man" mode and tell you to quit looking for stuff on youtube.  It great for watching cat videos or old cartoons.  It kind of sucks at anything that needs good explanations and details.

Try looking for education sites like [this one](https://education.jlab.org/qa/electromagnet.html) that go into detail, and explain things.

Comment: While the website does provide some details, the example image they show is very similar to the one OP built and is unlikely to provide significantly better performance. I don't think YouTube videos are always bad, they often show small details that are difficult to describe using text or images. Trying to find good creators on youtube might be a better idea than never using it.

Comment: Some YouTube videos do explain things well, but they are almost certainly not the videos with the most likes.

Answer (score 5):

That wire doesn't look insulated, so the current flows from the wire to the bolt and then up the other side. Or it takes some other short path.

Use magnet wire or regular insulated wire.

In order to make an electromagnet, you need the current to make **several turns** around the same cylindrical shape. Not 0.

---

If you, however, are super duper 100% sure that the wire is insulated, and you're using 12 V rated for 1 A to power it, then you are most certainly causing the power supply to turn off because you are exceeding the rated current. Not every power supply has that feature, but the one you are using might. If the power supply is not turning off due to you trying to take more current than what it is made for, then you will destroy the power supply. Try using a battery that you don't mind destroying instead.

---

If you want to power your coil correctly, assuming that it is a real coil, one that has insulated wire around it, then you should try pulsing current through it at a very high frequency. The higher the inductance, the lower the frequency you can get away with. My guesstimate frequency that you would need in order to keep the current continuously flowing in your inductor would be well above 100 kHz.

[This is the design](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333518/drive-relay-with-irfz44n) I'm thinking about that you would use to drive your coil (the one the questioner is showing). Remember, use a very high frequency for the switching, get some proper PWM signal at the input of the 1 kΩ resistor. And while you're at it, change the 1 kΩ resistor to 100 Ω to accommodate your *high frequency* switching (100 kHz).

If you do use the design as I linked, then you can use the 12 V rated for 1 A, the design will transform your 12 V down to maybe 120 mV (assuming 10% duty cycle, ignoring other problematic equations), and the resistance of the wire might be 100 mΩ, then the current will be 1.2 A. This is okay if you add a capacitor in parallel with your design so when you are taking 1.2 A, the capacitor will gladly give that extra 200 mA, and when you are not using it, the power supply will charge up the capacitor for the next time you need the 1.2 A pulse. Another inductor (that you buy) should be used together with that capacitor for best effect.

---

In case the design is hard to grasp, [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+1.0000000000000001e-7+2.3728258192205156+37+5+50%0Af+768+368+816+368+0+1.5+2%0AR+688+368+656+368+1+2+100000+2.5+2.5+0+0.05%0Ag+816+432+816+448+0%0Al+864+288+864+352+0+0.000047000000000000004+0.3666551619193904%0Aw+864+352+816+352+0%0Ad+816+352+816+192+1+0.5%0Ar+864+240+864+288+0+0.1%0Aw+864+192+864+240+1%0AR+736+96+736+64+0+0+40+12+0+0+0.5%0Aw+864+192+816+192+2%0Ax+952+222+999+333+4+24+I%5C%5Cn%5C%5CnESR%5C%5Cn%5C%5CnL%0Ax+648+404+707+434+4+24+5%25%5C%5CnPWM%0Ac+736+192+736+256+0+0.00001+12.005343335458765%0Ag+736+256+736+272+0%0Aw+736+192+816+192+0%0Al+736+128+736+192+0+0.001+0.016327893524998523%0Ar+688+368+768+368+0+100%0Ar+768+368+768+432+0+10000%0Aw+816+384+816+432+0%0Ag+768+432+768+448+0%0Ar+736+96+736+128+0+0.1%0Ax+667+119+714+230+4+24+ESR%5C%5Cn%5C%5CnL%5C%5Cn%5C%5CnC%0Ao+3+1+0+4098+20+3.2+0+2+3+3%0Ao+3+1+0+4353+20+1.6+1+2+3+3%0Ao+8+1+0+4097+20+0.05+2+2+8+3%0A) is what I'm talking about, the link goes to a simulation (CircuitJS).

Comment: It's a steel bolt, it acts as a shortcircuit at 100khz. It has no inductance at all at 100kHz

Comment: @Dorian See the link that I updated my answer with. That is what I'm talking about. I am not talking about inducing power into the steel bolt.  I am talking about treating the inductor for what it is, an inductor. - Or perhaps I'm missing something? - Out of curiousity, how should OP properly control her electromagnet? //serious question.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, I took back my upvote for the short version of the answer that used a battery. Which was a good answer and appropriate for somebody that has OP's knowledge in electronics. Seriously, the battery solution was a good choice for a school demo of an electromagnet. Upvote again but maybe you clean up the answer a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the other answers, it will be useful to understand [Ohms law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law):

U = R * i

Voltage = resistance * current

So, if you have 12V and 1A available, your coil needs to be at least 12 Ohm for you to run your PSU within specifications.

One way of checking resistance is by measuring with a multimeter. Another is by estimating by wire length times its resistance per meter (there are [tables](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/wirega.html) online which you can use).

As mentioned, the wire you are using is really thick and is probably trying to draw too much current from the power supply.

Resistance is proportional to the length of a conductor, and inversely proportional to the cross section. So, repeating, try longer and thinner wire.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the wire IS insulated, even though it does not look like it. If it is wire salvaged from a motor, transformer or another electromagnet, it definitely is. This kind of wire has a paint-like coating on it, and requires removing the insulation from the ends where you want to make a connection. Just scraping the coating off tends to still make unreliable connections.

With some types, you need to mechanically scrape it off (eg with a disposable knife and/or sandpaper) and THEN tin it with a soldering iron (tin should flow easily if the coating has been removed properly).

With other types, you can actually burn away the coating by holding the end in a bubble of solder on the tip of a very hot soldering iron - add extra solder/flux to get clean tinning after the coating is gone. TAKE THIS KIND OF WORK OUTSIDE or use a workspace with effective ventilation: Some of these coatings (eg polyurethane) are known to be silently toxic when burnt/melted, others (probably acrylic) will leave you and everyone around suddenly headached and/or slightly sick (from my anecdotal experience).

EDIT: If you are at an age where you are expected to ask a teacher or parent before using a knife, soldering iron, torch, or doing something that can potentially involve something toxic, do so.